# Integrate a delivery plan into a azure devops dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

I need to find a way to integrate a configured "delivery plan" into a dashboard in order to load that dashboard into MS teams. There is no widget available to integrate a delivery plan. Is there an extension which provides such functionality or does anyone have a hint?

I want to display all my epics for a specified period of time in a timeline.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, Currently there is no option to achieve this requirement.

You could try to create a query to fetch the results of the all epics for a specified period of time in a time line and then use the "Query Results" widget to dispaly the epics.

For more information of the query, you could refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

Comment: Thanks you. I already created a query and have a table result of all my epics. Is there a way to transform that table into a timeline view?

Comment: You could try to use the "Sprint Burndown" widget to dispaly a period of time of the epics to check if it fits your requirement. You could refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=remaining-work%2Cmay

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget to display a webpage.
[Webpage widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH8RM.png)
This way I was able to include a Delivery plan in a dashboard.